# Get images using google-cloud-containeranalysis

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I am using the following library to get docker images metadata from Java app:

```
implementation("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-containeranalysis:2.20.0")
```

On the google Artefact Registry side I enabled Vulnerability scanning for the repository: `Scanning: On`
But when I run this code, the result is always empty:

```
String projectId = "my-project";

        try (ContainerAnalysisClient containerAnalysisClient = ContainerAnalysisClient.create()) {
            ProjectName projectName = ProjectName.of(projectId);

            GetVulnerabilityOccurrencesSummaryRequest summaryRequest =
                GetVulnerabilityOccurrencesSummaryRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setParent(projectName.toString())
                    .build();

            VulnerabilityOccurrencesSummary summary =
                containerAnalysisClient.getVulnerabilityOccurrencesSummary(summaryRequest);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

I checked the vulnerability by calling this command:

```
gcloud artifacts docker images describe europe-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/docker/special-octo-sniffle:0.1.28-master.v024c820
```

And the result was returned correctly. I got a fully populated description of the image.

Why can't I get the output using ContainerAnalysisClient in Java? I assume the above code must return all the images metadata from the project?
Thank you in advance